# Is binomial expansion true for all kinds of matrices

Tags: symmetric-matrices

My teacher told me that, in case of square matrices, binomial expansion holds true if and only if they commute.  I am not able to figure out why they fail for other cases; any proof will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean.
$$(A+B)^3 = A^3 + 3 A^2 B + 3 A B^2 + B^3$$
also works for
$$ A = \pmatrix{a_{11} & 0\cr a_{21} & a_{22}\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{b_{11} & 0\cr b_{21} & -a_{11}-2 a_{22}-2b_{11}\cr} $$
which in general do not commute.

Comment: So there is no specific condition?

Comment: If they commute, $(A+B)^n = \sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} A^i B^{n-i}$ is true for all $n$.  For $n=2$, this is only true when they commute.  For other $n$, there are likely to be some other matrices for which it turns out to be true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$(A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)=A(A+B)+B(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$